# passing this through addEventListener

Tags: javascript, event-handling, this

I have a function that was previously working; but I have to make it wait now with `setTimeout`.  I thought I could just add an arrow function as the callback for the eventListener and still be able to pass `this` as the button for the context but I am getting an error.

```
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    setTimeout(checkAndRespond,1500);
});

//This is the line that throws the error
checkAndRespond = async function () {
    ...
    const row = this.parentElement.parentElement;
    ...
}
```

How am I supposed to pass `this` into the inner function?
Is the setTimeout context being passed in as `this` to checkAndRespond?
Is there something i am not understanding about how arrow functions work?

Comment: `setTimeout` does not pass a `this`.  And your arrow function drops its `this` anyway.

Comment: @SLaks regardless, I am looking for the button context and how to get that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How am I supposed to pass this into the inner function?

Which `this` ? Arrow functions take the context (`this`) of their parent functions, which is the global scope in this case and for that `this` points to `window`. If you want to call a function dynamically inside a certain context (that is what the `addEventListener`s do) you have to use a regular `function`.

> Is the setTimeout context being passed in as this to checkAndRespond?

No. You have to `.bind` the context manually:

```
 button.addEventListener("click", function() { // <- now we can work with this here
   setTimeout(checkAndRespond.bind(this), 1500); // <- and bind it
 });
```

Or you use the arrow functions behaviour as described above, and pass `this` as an argument:

```
 button.addEventListener("click", function() {
   setTimeout(() => checkAndRespond(this), 1500);
 });

 async function checkAndRespond(button) {
   //...
 }
```

Sidenotes:

You could also just use `button` instead of `this`, but that would probably be too easy.

`checkAndRespond =` is an undeclared (!!) variable, always declare them!